# How to get the ids of checked and unchecked checkbox items in a listbox in wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox

By default some listbox items are checked and some of them are uncheked.
Then user can able to change checked or unchecked the items.please tell me how to maintain the checked ids,unchecked ids ..

```
 private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListBoxItem checedItem = this.listBox2.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem((sender as CheckBox).DataContext) as ListBoxItem;
            if (checedItem != null)
            {
                checedItem.IsSelected = true;
            }

        }
private void CheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListBoxItem checedItem = this.listBox2.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem((sender as CheckBox).DataContext) as ListBoxItem;
            if (checedItem != null)
            {
                checedItem.IsSelected = false;
            }
        }

string result1 = e.Result.ToString();

                XDocument xmlDocu = XDocument.Load(new MemoryStream(System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result)));

                interestrates = (from rts in xmlDocu.Descendants("Friend")

                                 select new SampleCheckedData
                                 {

                                     Id = (string)rts.Element("userid"),
                                     Name = (string)rts.Element("name"),
                                     Icon = (string)rts.Element("imageurl"),
                                     IsChecked = !(Boolean)rts.Element("visiblestatus"),

                                 }).ToList<SampleCheckedData>();

                this.listBox2.ItemsSource = interestrates;

<ListBox x:Name="listBox2" SelectionMode="Multiple" Margin="0,67,0,0">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Stretch="Fill" MaxHeight="Infinity" MaxWidth="Infinity" Width="100" Height="100" />

                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Width="300" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="NoWrap" FontSize="22" />
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

EDIT:

```
 private void btnDone_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var checkedItems = from item in interestrates where item.IsChecked select item.Id;
            var uncheckedItems = from item in interestrates where !item.IsChecked select item.Id;
}
```

Please tell me how to maintain checked userids,unchecked userids.....

Comment: Also show the xaml of the checkboxes in the listbox

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are stashing your collection somewhere in your code and not just directly assigning it to the ListBox ItemsSource property, you should be able to simply look at the properties of your collection items...

```
var checkedItems = from item in interestrates where item.IsChecked select item;
var uncheckedItems = from item in interestrates where !item.IsChecked select item;
```

If you want just the userIds, then alter the query to something like

```
var checkedItems = from item in interestrates where item.IsChecked select item.Id;
var uncheckedItems = from item in interestrates where !item.IsChecked select item.Id;
```

Comment: why i am getting always null values in checkeditems,uncheckeditems ?

Comment: Without seeing your data, I don't know.  You may need to modify the code - it's there to give you an idea of what you need to do to achieve the solution you're after rather than being the exact code you need.

Comment: I am displaying checkboxes with default database values.after user checked and unchecked the checkboxes need to get the modified userids...please check my modify code...

Comment: Can you please help me i didn't get.

Comment: As I mentioned above, there is nothing I can do without seeing your data to figure out why the queries don't work.  Make sure that interestrates itself is not empty, and make sure you are using the correct LINQ query to pull the data out of the collection.